# Why are the grid points different?

Tags: calculus

So I noticed that the grid points for the midpoint and left Riemann sum were different I was confused as to why. Any explanation would be appreciated.

[image: Grid Points EXAMPLE 1]

Comment: Because the midpoint of an interval is different that the left hand point of the same interval.

Comment: In your specific problem, the grid points are different because the Reimann sums are over different intervals. In part (a), you are integrating over [1,3]. In part (b) you are integrating over [0,3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a Riemann sum on $[0,1]$ using *one* rectangle.

- For the left sum, $x_0 = 0$, since that is the left end of $[0,1]$.
- For the mid sum, $x_0 = 1/2$, since that is the midpoint of $[0,1]$.
- For the right sum, $x_0 = 1$, since that is the right end of $[0,1]$.

I will admit that when I have taught this material, I set 
$$  x_k = a + k \Delta x  $$
so that a Riemann sum on $n$ rectangles uses

- $a = x_0$ through $x_{n-1}$, for a left sum,
- $x_{1/2}$ [${}= x_{1-{1/2}}$] through $x_{n - 1/2}$, for a mid sum, and
- $x_1$ through $x_n = b$ for a right sum.

I have done this specifically to highlight the difference in the locations of the sample points in the three different sums (by not reusing the conflatable notation).

Here are the three interval rectangles for the Riemann sum of the same function.  Note that for left sums, we make the left edge of the rectangle have the same height as the function, for mid sum, the midpoint of the rectangle, and for the right sum, the right endpoint.

Left sum:

[image: left sum]

Mid sum:

[image: mid sum]

Right sum:

[image: right sum]

Comment: Still don't understand why the grid point values are what they are. For instance the mid sum for 0 was 1

Comment: @OGK : Have you *actually* sketched the curve and drawn the rectangles in the Riemann sum with the correct heights for the curve you sketched?

Comment: I got it now thanks!